# Indoor Positioning Solution without wifi connection

Tags: navigation, position, positioning, indoor-positioning-system

So we are working on the app which has indoor navigation.

We are looking for indoor positioning system (IPS) which can calculate the positioning on the device not on the cloud.

So if it does calculate the positioning on the cloud then it will have to have the persistent Wi-Fi connection which we don't want.

So for sure it will connect to Wi-Fi for the first time and download whatever it needs like radio maps and other stuff but after that if we loose the Wi-Fi we should still be able to get the positioning.

So can you guys please suggest any IPS provider which will be able to give the positioning even if internet connection is not available or limited, and it is calculating the positioning on the device not on the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

for your needs, I could recommend [Indoorway](https://www.indoorway.com) as it doesn't require a constant WiFi connection. You can once upload your data and use it then for indoor positioning purposes. Moreover, with Indoorway SDK - which works just like a plugin - you're able to integrate its features into your iOS or Android apps.